# Is Mutex required for 1 byte shared memory

Tags: c++, multithreading

my case is one thread read and want to 
decide if needed to change the value or not?

some thing like below

```
void set(bool status)
{ 
    if(status == m_status)
         return;
     monitor.lock();
     m_status = status;

}
```

if this possible?

Comment: Yes, like you did it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I want be sure. I know that when two thread want write even 1 byte this problematic. then I ask about that a thread want read without mutex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a synchronization object for boolean state is overkill.

On Windows you can use [Interlocked Variable Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For cross platform solution .. see [Boost Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/interprocess/detail/atomic.hpp)

`std::atomic` from C++11 is also a solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure all these instructions work on word sized (well at least 32bit) variables and not single bytes though..

Comment: If OP wants to use std::atomic from C++11.. It can do bool i think

Comment: parapura: you mean `char` (or better: `uint8_t`, not bool, but otherwise, you're correct. `std::atomic` can operate on all kinds of basic integer types.

Comment: gcc seems to be providing an bool one too..http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a00372.html

Comment: what is diffrent between "mutex" and "std::atomic" and "Interlocked Variable Access"

Comment: Interesting how that is implemented for different platforms - I thought Windows didn't provide these instructions for smaller values because it seems not necessarily portable to different architectures. But then I assume nothing says that `std::atomic<bool>` has to be only 1byte large.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to clarify your question a bit.  Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it necessary?  Probably.  Are there other ways to do it?  Yes, as another answer has noted.

Don't forget to unlock when you're done with the things you want to change.  And just a stylistic note, I find it much clearer to use your 'if' statement to encase the code block instead of return'ing out of the function.  Like this:

```
void set(bool status)
{ 
    if(status != m_status)
    {
        monitor.lock();
        m_status = status;
        monitor.unlock();
    }
}
```

Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I assume (hope) the OP's `monitor` is a RAII mutex, so there'd be no need to explicitly unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not possible. It will work most of the time on most platforms, but it's formally undefined and there are cases where cache coherency issues will come to hunt you.

If you can get C++11, use `std::atomic<bool>` from the new `<atomic>` header. If not, you should be using legacy compiler-specific equivalent. Windows have `Interlocked`* functions, GCC has `__sync` keyword. There is actually a cross-platform implementation of the important bits of the C++11 standard buried deep in Boost.Interprocess library, but it's unfortunately not exposed to the user.