# Qt example: no mutex lock when reading, why?

Tags: c++, qt, mutex

I am looking at [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-queuedcustomtype.html) example, and it raises a queston for me: when looking at [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-queuedcustomtype-renderthread-cpp.html) file a mutex is being used when accessing the global variable m_abort when its being changed. But when the run method reads from it, it does nothing with the mutex at all. Why?

Comment: You should ask why `m_abort` is not volatile :)

Comment: That was a really helpfull comment, thank you for the suggestion! =D

Comment: @Valeri Atamaniouk Good question :) I was wondering myself for a while about why it's not `volatile` - until it clicked for me that there are enough calls of external functions in the loop to prevent compiler from caching the global `m_abort` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I cannot see the purpose of the mutex at all.
Both reading and writing `m_abort` can be performed without mutex protection as it's a bool variable, and its value is changed atomically (at least on most platforms). And even if the write itself is not atomic and the variable can have an inconsistent value - it can be either false or true, and it will eventually be read as `true` (since the only value that is written there is `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Will work most of the time, but isn't the correct thing to do. It should be locked.

Also, check [Is Mutex required for 1 byte shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037289/is-mutex-required-for-1-byte-shared-memory) for further information.